# What is the name of this type of photos

Tags: images, style-identification

What is the name of this type of photos where all the characters are shown?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Uhm.. Composite? Collage?

Comment: A deep etched montage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you search for movie posters with several characters you'll find it's usually called a **Montage** or **Character Montage**. There's even a [super hero meme montage generator](https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/109499715/Superhero-Montage) so apparently it's also a meme somehow.

It seems that the type of composition doesn't matter, I've seen different arrangements and it's still called a montage. This type of composition used to be called simply a **collage** up until I googled it.

**Addendum:** [according to the Merriam-webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/montage), a Montage is (emphasis mine)

> 1. : the production of a rapid succession of images in a motion picture to illustrate an association of ideas
> 2. a : a literary, musical, or artistic [composite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/composite#h2) of juxtaposed more or less heterogeneous elements
>      b : **a composite picture made by combining several separate pictures**

Comment: I always thought "montage" was a video thing not a still image thing. Interesting.

Comment: @Scott apparently it is now... Montage used to be a video only thing AFAIK, but it seems times have changed.

Comment: Oxford Dictionary of English also lists ***"the technique of producing a new composite whole from fragments of pictures, text, or music"*** and gives examples of *"the art of montage in theatre and film"* and *"a montage of photographs"*

Comment: Thanks @GerardFalla I don't have a link to Oxford but I added a ref to the Merriam-Webster

Comment: @Luciano the OED also attests the usage is from 1938, so it's not a new meaning. *1938   A. Cooper, Making Poster 34:  "Used as ‘montage’ in conjunction with blue skies, or green fields, photographs of human beings appear singularly unattractive."*

Comment: @BillyKerr I think I just haven't been using english language for long enough, I always remember this type of... composite... as being a collage.

Comment: @Luciano "collage" and "montage" can be synonyms in this sense too. So, you're not wrong.